# Running an external program with sequential inputs from Julia 0.5.1

Tags: julia

I want to run an external program, lets call it `program`, sequentially piping inputs to its standard input. Lets call the inputs `input_1`, `input_2` etc.

I then want the standard output of the program to be piped back into memory, for example a Julia data structure, or if this is not possible, written to a text file.

I can run the external program with:

```
run(`program input_1 input_2`)
```

which results in the standard output of the program being displayed to the shell.

I however need to feed the inputs sequentially, so cannot use this approach.

I have looked on the [External Programs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/running-external-programs/) documentation page and I believe I should use the `open` function, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

When I run:

```
open(`program`)
```

the external program complains that it cannot run without an input.

[This](http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/julia-commands.html) blog post is quite informative, and I believe something like:

```
(si,pr) = writesto(`program`)
write(si,input_1)
...
write(si, input_2)
```

might have worked on an older version of Julia, but the `writeto` function has been deprecated, as discussed [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6945).

Additionally, I want the program to run in the background. Currently it spawns a new terminal window. I think this might be a function of the external program so I am not sure if this can be specified in Julia.

Comment: You need to look into how pipelines work in the docs http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/running-external-programs/
As to backgrounding it, you may be able to run it inside `nohup` (look up it's linux manpage).

Comment: Lyndon, I believed it was clear from my question that I did try to figure it out from the documentation, I actually linked to the same page that you refer to.  Although I tried to get it to work, as demonstrated in my question, I struggled to figure it out. I will look into the nohup.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your link to the docs.  I had to run, but thought I would at least give you the doc link, in case you had not. If I actually thought you hadn't done due diligence I would have just down voted; but you can miss stuff in the julia docs easily -- they are not yet hugely well written. I again have to run, and can't dig into what is going wrong with it right now for you.
Can I ask what program you are trying to run?

Comment: No problem, thanks for the doc link in that case. I'm trying to run [xfoil](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to see what I ended up implementing in Gaston (a plotting program based on gnuplot). I needed to start gnuplot, and then send it commands via its stdin, while reading its output through stdout and any errors through stderr.

I implemented a `popen3` function that executes a command and returns pipes to stdin, stdout, and stderr. The function is here: https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl/blob/master/src/gaston_aux.jl#L431

Then, I access gnuplot's stdout and stderr pipes using async tasks (because reading from them is blocking). You can see that happening here: https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl/blob/master/src/gaston_aux.jl#L5 all the way to line 52.

**Edit (June 2019):**

The best solution in Julia 1.x is to build a [`pipeline`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.pipeline-Tuple%7BBase.AbstractCmd%7D) to connect the pipes, and then [`run`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.run) to execute the pipeline. See [here](https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl/blob/c1416798f8aed1aa8f842f45220990537a6c43b3/src/Gaston.jl#L66-L75) for the current implementation in Gaston.

Unfortunately, the documentation for `Pipe` is still non-existent, so I still consider this solution to be unofficial.

Comment: These days there's a `readandwrite` function, but I think `stderr` may still be an issue with that.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Indeed, `readandwrite` cannot handle `stderr`, and it's scheduled for deprecation in 0.6. I haven't been able to find a way to replace my `popen3` function using `open` (or similar) base Julia commands.

Comment: Thank you MBaz.I am trying to do something similar (make a wrapper for an existing program) and it seems like I can learn allot from you program.

Comment: @Mike, you're welcome, and if you find a better solution, please do drop me a note in Gaston's issues :)

Comment: It didn't get deprecated in 0.6, but will be replaced in 1.0 with a method of `open` which returns a Process object that you can use to write to and read both stdout and stderr from. Details remain to be worked out.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski I thought it was deprecated in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19598, but now I see it survived.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski As of mid 2019 this is still an ugly problem. (Julia 1.1.0). Neither the documentation is comprehensive and useful (whats this stuff about ``other``), nor is the design of open any near of being intuitive. Instead of wasting time with backticked ``Cmd`` objects, I cannot really understand, I would much prefer an ``open`` where I can pass in endpoints for the redirected streams. Example: ``open(cmd,read = true, write = true, epin, epout, eperr )`` or have open return the redirects. Either is understandable. The status quo is cryptic.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski If no better ideas come to mind, you can still copy the design of .NET System.Diagnostics, which uses a ``StartupInfo`` object which can be configured before the process is created. There you can redirect to your hearts content and it does not take more than 5min of reading documentation to get it.

Comment: @BitTickler The documentation still leaves a lot to be desired, but the best solution I've found relies on `run` and `pipeline`, not `open`. See how I do this in Gaston: https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl/blob/master/src/Gaston.jl#L66-L78  (I've tested this code in Julia 1.1, but it probably also runs in 1.0)